# unity Assets\script\Produce.cs(10,20): error CS1002: ; expected resolution

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        trigger Square.AddComponent<Trigger>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void newObject(string Square) 
    {
        GameObject Instance = Instantiate (Square, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Instance.name = Square;
    }
}
```

Assets\script\Produce.cs(10,24): error CS1002: ; expected
Assets\script\Produce.cs(10,23): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

I get this error
What is the workaround?

Comment: `trigger` and `Square` in `Start()` haven't been defined or defined anywhere it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `trigger` and `square` and then assign the gameObject from editor (drag & drop).

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject square = null;

var trigger = square.AddComponent<Trigger>();
```

Also remove function `Update()` if you are not using it.